# MODX Rev setup not working in MAMP PRO

Tags: mamp, modx, modx-revolution, mamp-pro

I'm still having issues with setup MODX Rev 2.5.8 in localhost as I have already set up database via mySQL, please see screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjdZU.png

How do I fix this issues?

Thanks,

Shaun.

Comment: Have you checked if that file exists in the path and is readable? Were you able to run setup ok?

Comment: A 500 error is an internal server error. So your MAMP log should give you a hint about the error.

Comment: Include the relevant error in the error log